# CFWEBSOCKET - unable to call websocket object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, websocket, coldfusion-10, cfwebsocket

I'm using the cfwebsocket tag in Coldfusion to create a web socket connection.
I looked at an example from here http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/03/html5-websockets-in-coldfusion-10.html
and near the end it shows you all the javascript calls you can make on the web socket object.
However, when I try to make any call on it I get an error that it is undefined.
For example I have:

```
<cfwebsocket name="ws" onMessage="messageHandler" onOpen="openHandler" onClose="closeHandler" onError="errorHandler" subscribeTo="chat" />
```

and in my javascript i call

```
alert(ws.isConnectionOpen());
```

and I get the error in firebug: TypeError: ws is undefined.

Anyone know why I can't call it?
My chat works fine and I can connect and chat properly. I just wanted to close the connection when the chat ended so I was looking into how it's done calling the websocket but I don't know why it's not working.

Note that I am using jQuery and the javascript is wrapped in the document ready.

Comment: Is it possible that your alert is firing before the socket is established (defined)?

Comment: That was my initial thought but I wrapped the alert in a document.ready() and also placed it at the very end of my code but same result.

Comment: Seems like the websocket can't be called from the document.ready function.
When I called it from a function from a click event then it worked. So I guess it wasn't loaded before the call in document.ready which is weird since Coldfusion should have created the object already. This is still a problem for me because I need to get the number of subscribers along with other data when the page is initially loaded and not from a click event. Wonder if anyone else is having this issue.

Comment: Can you do it from the onOpen handler? Or another handler?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't interact with the ws object till it establishes a connection to the server.

There are a couple of ways to handle this scenario.  You can use the "onOpen" attribute and have it call a function once the web socket connect has been established.

However, you are probably better off just using the "onMessage" attribute and create a generic  listener function that processes all web socket messages from the server.

```
function messageHandler(msg) {

    if (msg.type == 'response' && msg.reqType == 'welcome'){

        alert('user connected');
    }       
}
```